# Output ffmpeg to certain format

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, media

I have a media file with the following format according to ffprobe:

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A 
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: M4A mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2013-03-21 07:05:30
  Duration: 00:00:00.42, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 118 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 100 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-03-21 07:05:30
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
```

Is it possible to have ffmpeg output to exactly this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encode an AAC stream with these parameters using a command like this:

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -map 0:a -acodec libfdk_aac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 100k out.m4a
```

Any supported input format can be used in place of `wav`.

If your ffmpeg is not configured with `libfdk_aac` you can use `-acodec libfaac` or `-acodec aac -strict experimental` instead.  See ffmpeg's [AAC Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/AACEncodingGuide) for more details on the different AAC encoders.

The container will have the major brand `M4A` but not those exact values for minor_version and compatible_brands.  If you need those values you can change them with [mp4box](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/).  For example this will set the major brand to `M4A` with minor version 0, and remove `iso2` (added by ffmpeg) from the list of compatible brands:

```
mp4box -brand "M4A :0" -rb iso2 out.m4a
```

Comment: How to change major brand with ffmpeg? Not mp4box